# How to fix a SanDisk USB 3.0 Flash drive connected as HiSpeed instead of SuperSpeed?

Tags: windows-7, usb, usb-flash-drive, speed

I'm using a SanDisk "[Ultra Fit](https://www.sandisk.com/home/usb-flash/ultra-fit-usb)" Flash drive (32 GB) which is a USB 3 device on a blue USB 3 port of a [Lenovo W510](https://www.lenovo.com/shop/americas/content/pdf/notebooks/ThinkPad/W-Series/W510_datasheet.pdf).

- [image] [image]

Whatever port I use, I get the message "This device can perform faster".

This is what USB Device Tree Viewer reports:

- [image]

The flash drive is connected to Port 4 as HighSpeed, even if it reports being able to connect in SuperSpeed mode:

- [image]

The computer port itself seems working as I can use normally other USB 3 devices, and the Flash drive itself is correctly recognized as USB 3 on another computer. I tried another Flash drive, same model but 16 GB, the problem is similar, as if there was something wrong with this type of Flash drive.

I have read other questions about similar problems, e.g. [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/700254/usb-3-0-flash-drive-wont-work-in-superspeed-mode-under-windows-8) but to no avail. How can I fix this?

Comment: with the drive disconnected uninstall and reinstall the usb 3.0 root hub in device manager, the try again.

Comment: @Moab: Thanks! It didn't work, same as before. What I did: Uninstalled / reinstalled NEC root hub, no joy; Uninstalled root hub and host controller, rebooted, reinstalled, no joy.

Comment: Does it work properly on any other pc?

Comment: @Moab: Yes on another Thinkpad it shows as SuperSpeed in USB Tree Viewer (with an Intel chip). Conversely if I connect another USB 3 device to the same port, it is recognized as SuperSpeed.

Answer (score 1):

Lenovo W510 is a six-years old computer. At the time there were no functional USB3 controllers from INTEL, so OEMs used the original NEC PCIe->USB3 bridge to support USB3.0.

There were quite a few issues with NEC controller on Lenovo laptops as well. The NEC chip does have an upgradable firmware, and there should be an utility in NEC driver package to check the version. I would recommend to google for most recent NEC drivers and update your USB drivers and firmware. Try to find generic NEC drivers (now Renesas), they might perform better than the original Lenovo-supported drivers.

https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/22775/USB-3-0-Renesas-Electronics-USB-3-0-Firmware-Updates

Comment: Good information, thanks. After applying both updates of the link, lower port shown as USB3/SS, upper port still as USB2/HS. I then reinstalled NEC firmware 3025 and drivers 1.0.19.0: No change! Now I'm confused: The lower port could have already worked when I posted my question -(    Didn't find firmware newer than 3025 (cont'd)

Comment: Driver 1.0.19.0 sounds like an ancient drier. Intel website shows Renesas drivers as "Version: 4.0.2.1; 2.0.2.0 (Latest)". The change in port number is normal, SS port1 is associated with HS port3, and port2 with port4.

Comment: It seems I've a uPD720200 version 3, and the Intel links are for version 4, they don't install but I needed to run them in CMD to realize. I upgraded the firmware to 3.0.3.4 [from here](http://drivers.softpedia.com/downloadTag/uPD720200). Then I tried different NEC/Renesas drivers (2.1.39.0 and 2.1.36.0) from the same source, but either they detected the Flash memory as USB 2, either the memory was recognized as unformatted after a timeout. If you don't have other ideas, I think I'll give up after several hours of install, uninstall, reboot :-)

Comment: That's why I added "good luck", but it was edited out by moderator. Did you try to clean the SS contacts with toothbrush and isopropyl alcohol? In both connectors? Bend the connection to some degree? You clearly have some marginal electric behavior, your SS port does not "like" your drive. It is either Rx_detect failure, or something with signal levels. You can also try a USB3.0 extender, passive or active, just to change electrical [mis]match in one way or anther.

Comment: I don't think there is any electrical problem, other devices consistently connect as USB 3 while the 3 Flash drives of this model I've have the same problem on this computer only (and only on one port). Thanks again Ali!

Comment: There could be several problems with signals. For example, your Flash drive is electrically short and can output too much of signal and, since the USB3.0 link is self-adaptive, the NEC circuit might be overloaded and training algorithm can fail to converge to reasonable settings. Did you try the passive extender as I suggested?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43587/discussion-between-mins-and-ali-chen).